# Construct a Grammar for a language that includes mod

Tags: formal-grammar

I am trying to construct a regular grammar for the following language:

$$L = \{ w \ | \ (na(w) - nb(w))\mod3!= 1 \}.$$

I'm struggling to understand what it is this language produces, and thus struggling to create a grammar for it.

We want a combination of $a$'s and $b$'s such that the difference of the two, $\mod 3$ is not equal to $1$. We know that $1, 4, 7, 10, 13,\dots, \mod 3 = 1$. With that being said, some valid strings would consist of:

- the same amount of $a$'s and $b$'s // $0 \mod 3 = 0$,
- three $a$'s for every 1 $b$        // $3-1 = 2 \mod 3 = 2$.

So I've started with this, but I'm lost on how to include the same amount of $a$'s and $b$'s.

$S \rightarrow aaabS \ | \ \lambda   \hspace{1cm}$ (this takes care of the empty string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a DFA accepting the language. Let the states be $Q = \{q_0, q_1, q_2\}$. I assume the alphabet is $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$ The idea is: after processing a string $s \in \Sigma^{*}$, the machine will be in state $q_i$ if $count(a, s) - count(b, s) = i$, where $count(x, s)$ is the number of $x$s in $s$. Clearly the starting state has to be $q_0$: the empty string has the same number of $a$s and $b$s.

Then it's easy to see what the transition function $\delta \colon Q \times \Sigma \to Q$ has to be:
$$
(q_0, a) \mapsto q_1 \\
(q_0, b) \mapsto q_2 \\
(q_1, a) \mapsto q_2 \\
(q_1, b) \mapsto q_0 \\
(q_2, a) \mapsto q_1 \\
(q_2, b) \mapsto q_0 \\
$$

Because you want to recognize strings with $count(a, s) - count(b,s) \neq 1$ (mod 3), the accepting states are $A = \{q_0, q_2\}$.

So the DFA is $(\Sigma, Q, \delta, A, q_0)$.

#### Grammar

Here's a right regular grammar whose three nonterminals $S_0, S_1, S_2$ mimic the states $q_0, q_1, q_2$ of the DFA above (starting symbol is $S_0$):

$$
\begin{align}
S_0 &\to a S_1 \mid b S_2 \mid \Lambda \\
S_1 &\to a S_2 \mid b S_0 \\
S_2 &\to a S_1 \mid b S_0 \mid \Lambda \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't think that $S_2\to \ldots |\Lambda$ is intended

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down in detail. It's a very nice approach to the problem. To test my understanding; Lets say we wanted to recognize strings with count(a,s) - count(b,s) != 0 (mod 3). The accepting state would then be just {q0}, correct?

Comment: Oops no: if you want to recognize strings with count(a,s) - count(b,s) != 0 (mod 3), then you want the difference of counts to be either 1 or 2 (yes?) So the accepting states would be $\{q_1, q_2\}$. If $q_0$ were the only accepting state, then the language accepted would be: all strings s with count(a,s) = count(b,s) (mod 3).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry a miscommunication between my brain and fingers! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen No? We want to accept strings $s$ with derivations $S_0 \Longrightarrow^* s S_2$

Comment: If we wanted strings where count(a,s) - count(b,s) = odd, the only accepting state would be {q1}, am I correct in this?

Comment: @Talen Kylon yep, correct.